# Is "timestamp" really deprecated?

Tags: sql-server

Microsoft recommends that we use `rowversion` instead of `timestamp`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

However, I can't see how to do this.

The referenced T-SQL documentation says:

> If you do not specify a column name, the SQL Server Database Engine generates the timestamp column name; however, the rowversion synonym does not follow this behavior. When you use rowversion, you must specify a column name, for example:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE ExampleTable2 (PriKey int PRIMARY KEY, VerCol rowversion) ;
> ```

However, when I use this code to generate the table, the column in SSMS is shown as:

```
  Colum Name: VerCol

  Data type: timestamp
```

Is there a way to use `rowversion` in SQL Server?

Comment: You are using rowversion properly. Unfortunately, there are still remnants of the legacy  `timestamp` for the data type name in the tools and engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the `timestamp` **syntax** is deprecated, i.e. specifying a column by its type without specifying its name. Underneath, it's still `timestamp`, type id = 189; try `select * from sys.types where system_type_id = 189`. `rowversion` keyword was just used to differentiate between the two. These are equivalent:

```
CREATE TABLE a (id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1), VerCol timestamp)
CREATE TABLE b (id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1), VerCol rowversion)
```

Both these tables will look and behave exactly the same. Try

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id in (OBJECT_ID('dbo.a'), OBJECT_ID('dbo.b'))
```

you'll see both `VerCol` columns have the same `system_type_id`. If you try:

```
INSERT INTO a DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO b DEFAULT VALUES

SELECT * FROM a
SELECT * FROM b
```

You'll get something like:

```
id          VerCol
----------- ------------------
1           0x00000000000007D3

(1 row affected)

id          VerCol
----------- ------------------
1           0x00000000000007D4

(1 row affected)
```

The VerCol values will of course be different for your database.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I much prefer the term rowversion and for it to appear as the datatype.

Comment: I would too, especially given timestamp means something else in all other RDBMSs and the ISO standard. I don't think it's ever going to change though, could break user application compatibility which might be too much of a risk.